# How to select parent within a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have a list, declared like so:

```
<ul>
  <li class="yearCategory"><a href="javascript:void(0)">2011</a></li>
  <ul class="subCategory">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">January</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">February</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

When 'January' or 'February' are selected, I would like to return the 'yearCategory' value of that certain list, in this case 2011.

How can this be done with jQuery? I've tried experimenting with parent and parents, but have not managed to select the correct element.

This is what i've tried so far:

```
$(this).parent("ul").next("li")
```

Comment: Offtopic but still good to know: you may not nest <ul> elements. A <ul> can only contain <li> elements.

Comment: Show us your approach with parent...because, that must  be the way to go.

Comment: @Baszz But a `<li>` element *can* contain `ul` elements again as far as I know...

Comment: @Marnix agree, as u say, far as i know

Comment: @Marnix: I'm sure it's not valid...you can however add an <ul> inside an <li> element.

Comment: @Baszz, that's what I said. ;)

Comment: var sub = $('.subCategory'); sub.click(function(){ sub.siblings().eq(0).children().text(); });

Comment: have we answered your question? Or did we misunderstand?

Answer (score 4):

firstly I'm pretty sure what you have is invalid markup your nested ul should be within the li element like so:

```
<ul>
  <li class="yearCategory">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">2011</a>
      <ul class="subCategory">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">January</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">February</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

secondly without more of your code I can't guess at how you've set this up - this is a general howto select a parent.

```
$('.subCategory li a').click( // The element that you are actually clicking is an A tag
    function()
    {
        var parent = $(this) // A tag
          .parent() // LI Tag
          .parent() // UL Tag
          .parent(); // Wrapper LI Tag

        alert($('a', parent).html()); // Output the HTML contents of the parents A tag
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your mark up slightly since the original wasn't valid:

```
<ul>
  <li class="yearCategory">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">2011</a>
    <ul class="subCategory">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">January</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">February</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.subCategory li a').click(function() {
        var year = $(this)
                     .parent()
                     .parent()
                     .parent()
                     .find('a')
                     .text();

        alert(year); // or whatever you want to do with the year
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your starting element is that a-Tag (containing the Text 'January').
To get to the value of 2011, you should do this:

```
var result = $start.parent().parent().prev().find("a").text();
```

chain would be like:
first parent gets you to "li" containing your "a".
second parent gets you to "ul" containing that "li".
prev gets you to the element before your "ul" element, so your li with class "yearCategory".
then find your a-Tag containing the text you want.

For example, if your startelement was not your "a"-Tag, but the "li"-Tag, you would need one less "parent"-Function:

```
var result = $start.parent().prev().find("a").text();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be the following:

```
$("li.yearCategory a:fisrt", $(anchorNode).parent().parent()).text();
```

...but to simplify things I would add an id to the parent ul, by allowing a simple selector like:

```
$("ul#myid li.yearCategory a:first").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the mark-up you have provided, this should work -

```
$("a").click(function () {
    alert($(this).parents('ul').find('li.yearCategory > a').text())
})
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/Krtcs/

You'd have to be careful with this as it will fire for all 'a' clicks, but will only work when the link is nested in the same way that the 'January' and 'February' links are.

Also, as Tomalak Geret'kal points out in the comments below the code will work with the mark-up provided in the OP, it could fail depending on the mark-up surrounding it.

Comment: This potentially breaks when the entire thing is inside some still-higher-level list.